# How to set google chart API locale

Tags: google-visualization

I want to set the language of the google chart API to a value.
It currently uses the language of the browser visiting the page.
How do I set it to the language of my application?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

See Google docs [Loading Charts using a specific locale](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/library_loading_enhancements#loadwithlocale).

*By default, the Google Chart libraries are loaded with the locale specified by the browser. You can override this default by explicitly specifying a locale in the loading parameters.*

For example:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart'], 'language': 'ja'});
```

Comment: If I want to change to Chinese, how do I know the code? Is it "cn", "zh", "zhcn"? Is there a page listing all supported locales?

Comment: The documentation now says: "By default, the Google Charts is loaded with the "en" locale. You can override this default by explicitly specifying a locale in the loading settings."