# Google chart Dutch currency pattern

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I've got a Google line chart which I'm trying to customize:

```
    var options = {
        title: '',
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
        colors: ['red','green','blue'],
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Weken',
            titleTextStyle : { italic: 0 }
            },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Voergewicht',
            titleTextStyle : { italic: 0 },
            format: '€ #.###,##  '
        }
    };
```

I would like to format the vAxis values like this: `€ 12.345,67`, so a dot as thousand separator. But using the pattern above, it sees the `.` as decimal separator. How can I  accomplish that?

Comment: I think you need to set the locale, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399369/how-to-set-google-chart-api-locale

Comment: @RobAu, yes, you're right! Please add it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the proper locale (nl).

> By default, the Google Chart libraries are loaded with the locale
>   specified by the browser. You can override this default by explicitly
>   specifying a locale in the loading parameters.

For example:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart'], 'language': 'nl'});
```